# How to search an array of strings using wildcard

Tags: java, string, search, wildcard

I'm trying to write a simple program that will search an array of string and output all the value which first sets of letters starts with what is in JTextfield

```
String[] words= {"apples", "applets", "ash", "bass", "banana", "cat", "chat", "coke"};
```

what I want is when my textfield contains nothing all of the words would appear, if "app" then only apples and applets will be displayed.

Comment: Have you looked at [`String#contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29)?

Comment: You may try `startsWith` function of `String`

Comment: Have you looked at `String#startsWith`?

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over the strings an evaluate each one with `startsWith`:

```
private static String[] filterWords(String[] words, String prefix) {
    List<String> filtered = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (prefix == null || prefix.lenght() == 0 || word.startsWith(prefix)) {
            filtered.add(word);
        }
    }
    return filtered.toArray(new String[filtered.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate your array element one by one, use [String.startsWith(prefixText)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) function to check your string is start with search text, add your search element in one List and convert that list into array return that array.

For Example :

```
public String[] searchText(String[] strArray,String searchTxt)
{
    if(searchTxt == null || searchTxt.length()==0)
        return strArray;

    List<String> resultArray = new LinkedList<String>();
    for (String word : strArray) {
        if (word.startsWith(searchTxt)) {
            resultArray.add(word);
        }
    }
   return resultArray.toArray(new String[resultArray.size()]);
}
```

If your search string's length is zero than return you original array without iterating your array.

Answer (score 0):

A little more efficient solution especially with large arrays would be:

```
private static String[] filterWords(String[] words, String prefix) {
    List<String> filtered = new LinkedList<String>();


if (prefix == null || prefix.lenght() == 0){
    return words;
}
else{
    for (String word : words) {
         if(word.startsWith(prefix)) {
            filtered.add(word);
        }
    }
    return filtered.toArray(new String[filtered.size()]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done very efficiently and concisely with Java 8 Lambdas:

```
    String[] words = {"apples", "applets", "ash", "bass", "banana", "cat", "chat", "coke"};
    String searchText = "app"; //Coming from the TextArea

    String[] results = Arrays.stream(words)
            .filter(item -> item.startsWith(searchText))
            .toArray(size -> new String[size]);
```